# How to clean water damaged Lifepo4 batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium, lifepo4, corrosion, cleaning

What is the best way to clean water damaged rusted lithium Lifepo4 batteries?

[image: rusted cells]I have six used 16sXp 48v 5kwh server rack batteries that look to have been sitting in water and have rusted.  There is still some voltage and I would like to charge it, but need to clean it first.

Comment: Call it "Dark Energy" and sell it as art sculpture. I think this is beyond any other use case. The cells are probably no longer sealed. Even if you clean it, chances are low to balance such a pack again. Do you have a good insurance?

Comment: They were a recycler/dismantle find.  I might separate the cells out, only the bottom ones look this bad.

Comment: There is zero chance of these ever working again. Recycle them.

Comment: "some voltage" doesn't cut it. The voltage has to be above 2 V or the cells are toast.

Comment: The bottom four Xp groups are toast.  The other 12 Xp groups still have about 3.1v to 3.2v.